# Why does AJAX POST is not working on IE with MVC controller and is null?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, internet-explorer

As the title says, the main problem of AJAX POST is in Internet explorer 11 but not in other browsers. I'm developing with ASP MVC, Jquery, AJAX with JSON, and everything seems to work fine with Firefox and Chrome. 
The GET request with ajax was solved already, but the POST request is having problems with Internet Explorer. I've read many questions and posibble solutions for this like using **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",** not using **cache**, etc. But for some reason the POST request works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

The flow is:

1. The user choose some products and this products are added to a complex json object.
2. When the object is ready to be sent, I call the "PostData()" function with javascript
3. On Firefox and Chrome the JSON.stringify works fine and send that string to the controller and the model binding detects every parameter sent. But for some reasons, IE is not working.

Now that I've explained the issue here is the relevant code

View:

```
function PostData() {

    var json = JSON.stringify({orders: Orders, cart: Cart});

    $.ajax({

        url: "@Url.Action("Buy", "Shop")",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        //I can stringify here, or in a new variable but nothing changes
        data: json,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {    
            alert(textStatus);
            },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Was posted");
        }
    });
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Buy(Products products)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // code I'm gonna execute
        }

        return Json(new { Success = true});
    }
```

Model

```
 public class Products
    {
        public Cart cart { get; set; }
        public Orders orders{ get; set; }
    }
```

The Products class is a view model of two other models as the code shows, but that's not the problem because on Firefox and Chrome every parameter from JSON is populated with MVC. Only Internet Explorer can't handle that and my model is null (both models)

Even using Firebug Lite on Internet Explorer detects the json object populated that is going to be sent but is always null on Internet Explorer on the controller. I don't know what could be the problem.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
NEw information, I needed to create another page with same functionality, and now I see that single "parameters" are obtained in IE, but a **List model** is null, I don't know why

**EDIT 2**

Making test, I realize only on IE9 the JSON ARRAY was catched on the controller, but for Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11 is null. I still can't find the solution for this.

Comment: Is your IE11 running in quirks mode? I think IE only supports JSON and its methods in standard mode. Run developer tools in IE and emulate standard mode and see if the issue persists. It might be safer to reference a json library such as json2.js so you arent relying on the browsers compatability. Alterntaively you can specify a doctype to force standard mode. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response and is not running in quirks mode. I already run on standard mode and nothing changes, is still null. And I can't use standard mode it "destroy" the website. And the json2.js I can't use external libraries except jquery.

Comment: In IE use developer tools > network activity and see what gets sent over the wire. Can you see the parameters in your XHR? Also is there any particular reason your ajax is not async?

Comment: I did what you told me and it seems nothing is sent (the reason of the post). And about why is not async it's nothing in particular, I change it to true for test and the same result, null.

Comment: @JorgeF: did you mean you can't use *quirks* mode, as it "destroys" the website?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, what I know about quirks mode it's about "compatibility mode", trying to view something in basic mode, but maybe I'm wrong about what is quirks mode.

Comment: Press F12. Does it say Standards mode or compatibility mode. If it's in compatibility mode, you must use json2.js or get it out of compatibility mode.

Comment: Sorry but my browser is in spanish, but I already investigate what everyone means about "Standard mode" and IE 11 says "Edge (default)", so I must assume that's the standard mode. So it's in standard mode and it's not working.

Comment: I tried the json2.js even if I can't use it, and the model is still empty. And I don't know why the question was downvote.

Comment: Im sorry to hear you're still having trouble. If the data isn't getting sent from your client then we can run out your mvc code and its model binder causing the issue. Your JSON data is stored in a variable called JSON - Try and change this to something else. I have a feeling JSON might be a reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but It's not about the var "json" because on Firefox and Chrome works perfect and I already make a lot of research about json array o list items to MVC and it seems to be a common problem but I already implement all the solutions in other questions but nothing seems to work on IE.

Comment: @JorgeF did you find the solution for this? I am getting same issue... only with IE not with Chrome or FF. Let me know if you have a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: @gmsi Back then it was an IE extension (something related to Google extension). The question with the ajax request has a "cache: false" make sure you have that in your ajax request because IE usually cache the requests and happened to me too a long time ago. And make sure you don't have a IE extension installed by default that could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeF I dont have IE extension installed and also have the cache: false in the call.